# .NET configuration file - Do I need to include it in installer?

Tags: .net, installation, configuration-files

I have a C# application `MyApp.exe` that targets .NET 3.5. In order to support other versions, I used [MSDN instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and created a config file `MyApp.exe.config`, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

My question is what should I do with this file? Do I need to include it in the installer and put near the exe file on the target computer? I couldn't find any instructions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to include it in the installer and put near the exe file on the target computer?

Yes.  This file needs to exist next to the installed exe post-deployment.

Most installers that understand .NET deployment will automatically handle this for you, so it's likely you won't need to "do" anything special (other than verify it got copied across correctly.)

Comment: Thank you! Can you please provide a reference to that? (by the way, I use NSIS installer, which doesn't install this config file automatically)

Comment: @Serg There isn't much other than the main app config reference material: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374182(v=vs.85).aspx  The file is read at startup, though, to change the supported runtimes.  If you don't include it, the information won't be available to use on the other system, so you'll get the default binding behavior (which is obviously not what you want)